# If an exception is thrown from IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext() or .Current, must it be still be disposed?

Tags: c#, exception, dispose, idisposable, ienumerator

Intuitively I think yes, but I'm not sure if there's some convention I don't know about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we can't know what the implementation is, the only safe answer is "yes".

However, it is very rare to use `IEnumerator` directly - `foreach` being more common. For the generic `IEnumerator<T>` you can use a using statement:

```
using(var iter = obj.GetEnumerator()) {
    ...
}
```

Even without the generic version, you can cheat:

```
IEnumerator iter = obj.GetEnumerator();
using(iter as IDisposable) {
    ...
}
```

Which will dispose iter if it is IDisposable

Answer (score 0):

No disposable object *MUST* be disposed, ever.<sup>[1]</sup>

But they *should* be. As a `using` block uses the `finally` clause to dispose and this is executed whether the `using` block is exited normally or via an exception, the default is to dispose even in the face of an exception.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I suppose one could have a buggy implementation where a non-managed resource is held and there is no finaliser, but the correct action there is to implement a finaliser.

Comment: When the `IDisposable` object could be a connection, a file, a transaction etc (i.e. something that can be contested; and note this could be inside an iterator block, so apply to the `IEnumerator` case) - then waiting on a non-deterministic GC could be very bad. IMO "must" is very appropriate.

Comment: @Marc: MUST means mandatory, not doing it is inherently an error. SHOULD means: you need a good reason not to. And commentary in the Framework Design Guidelines (section 9.4) disagrees: [Joe Duffy] "you should do your best to call Dispose when you are done with the object. But if ownership becomes tricky (because the object is referenced from multiple places or shared across threads, for example), neglecting to call Dispose will do no harm.". That is, I assume "no harm" locally, clearly if a resource is locked you have a problem, but that is not always the case.

Comment: @Richard - since he can't predict the implementation, the best he can argue is that it "should" do no harm; and "should"-multiplied is introducing a lot of unpredictability. I see what you are *saying*, but *personally* I'd rather see the "dispose it" argument reinforced as strongly as possible. But well argued, and valid (+1) but arguably misleading-to-beginners-hoping-to-be-lazy.

Comment: Winforms' Control.Dispose() is an example I know of where not disposing causes an irrecoverable leak.  Such is the trouble, no golden rule.

Comment: @Richard: There are many cases in which it is not practical to assure effective cleanup of a non-disposed IDisposable; indeed, the IEnumerable situation mentioned here is one of them.  As a simple scenario, suppose an IEnumerable needs to receive notification when a collection is about to be modified (e.g. because implements lazy snapshot semantics using copy-on-write).  If the collection is long-lived, and is frequently enumerated but never modified, every enumerator will live as long as the collection.  MAJOR memory leak.

Comment: @Richard: Properly disposing of shared objects isn't always practical (because one has no idea which user will be the last to need an object), and objects which are designed to be shared should finalize themselves cleanly when no longer needed.  Unless one knows an object may be safely abandoned, however, one MUST dispose of IDisposable objects before abandoning them; code which doesn't is broken.  That isn't to say the rest of a system shouldn't attempt to do the best it can with broken code, but the fact that the system may usually handle things ok doesn't mean the code's not broken.

Comment: @supercat: I suggest reading the full (i.e. get the book) coverage in the design guidelines to better understand this. There is no MUST (in the technical sense), MS explicitly say this. Hence SHOULD. A collection which notifies its enumerators to invalidate/disconnect themselves can drop its reference to them as well, thus they are available for GC as soon as their client removes its reference.

Comment: @Richard: While the enumerators will be eligible for GC once the collection itself becomes eligible, that may not occur for a long time.  If the collection is held by a static object, it may not happen at all before application shutdown.  It's not uncommon for some collections to be enumerated many thousands or even millions of times during the lifetime of an application.  If that is done with an enumerator uses events, and if the routine which creates the enumerators doesn't Dispose them, how can the collection know which events to detach?  It can't.  Memory leak.

Comment: @Richard: It is unfortunate that Microsoft doesn't really distinguish between Disposable objects that may generally be safely abandoned, and those which cannot, and even more unfortunate that it is often needlessly sloppy in taking care of IDisposable objects and event hooks.  Microsoft can hardly say one "must" do something it routinely fails to do.  Nonetheless, given that it is impossible to make all IDisposable objects robust in the face of abandonment, it cannot be safe to assume objects can handle abandonment unless the contracts of those particular objects require it.